# Oculus hand grab detection with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

In my Unity VR project I am using OculusInteractionSampleRig with hand detection.
How can I detect when an object is grabbed and is released with hands?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```cs
public class GrabLog : OVRGrabbable
{
    public override void GrabBegin(OVRGrabber hand, Collider grabPoint)
    {
        base.GrabBegin(hand, grabPoint);
        Debug.Log("Grabbed");
    }

    public override void GrabEnd(Vector3 linearVelocity, Vector3 angularVelocity)
    {
        base.GrabEnd(linearVelocity, angularVelocity);
        Debug.Log("Released");
    }
}
```

I tried this too but it doesn't work, either:

```cs
public class GrabLog : MonoBehaviour
{
    private OVRGrabbable _ovrGrabbable;

    private void Start()
    {
        _ovrGrabbable = GetComponent<OVRGrabbable>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_ovrGrabbable.isGrabbed && !_ovrGrabbable.wasGrabbedLastFrame)
        {
            Debug.Log("Grabbed");
        }
        else if (!_ovrGrabbable.isGrabbed && _ovrGrabbable.wasGrabbedLastFrame)
        {
            Debug.Log("Released");
        }
    }
}
```